# Notepad++ Regex: Match the first search result (or the second search result)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this line repeating:

```
<ul class="lista_3">
<ul class="lista_3">
<ul class="lista_3">
```

How can it match only the first search result? And how can I match only the second search result?

Comment: Just press find once? Then press it a second time?

Comment: What does your regex look like?

Comment: I have to change in 1600 files, so I have to use Replace All, that is the problem. So I cannot use find once / find again..

I try this  `^.*(<ul class="lista_3">)((?s:)).*/` but it is not very good

Comment: Why do you need to search and replace them one by one?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/fR0xU5/1 here is some solution, you can try to play with number in `{...}`. But if this can not solve your problem. So, that means you give us a bad text example. Please give us an example that close to your real text file but to be minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match and replace the first occurrence only, you need to bear in mind that regex engines match from left to right, and that Notepad++ regex engine needs to consume the whole document in order not to retry at the next line.

Enable the *`.` matches newline* option and use

```
<ul class="lista_3">(.*)\z
```

where `<ul class="lista_3">` is the literal text and `(.*)` is a capturing group with ID 1 that matches any 0+ characters up to the end of the document (`\z`). Note that if you need to replace the first occurrence, use something like `<ul class="Moja_nowa_lista_1">$1` (where `$1` is the backreference to the captured value).

[image]

To match and replace the second occurrence, you need to match the first occurrence first, and use either tempered greedy tokens or lazy dot matching.

```
\A(.*?<ul class="lista_3">.*?)<ul class="lista_3">(.*)\z
```

or (with a tempered greedy token)

```
\A((?:(?!<ul class="lista_3">).)*<ul class="lista_3">(?:(?!<ul class="lista_3">).)*)<ul class="lista_3">(.*)\z
```

And replace with `$1<ul class="Moja_nowa_lista_2">$2`.

[image]

Comment: by the way Wiktor, I had another words after `<ul class="lista_3">` in the same line, what should be the Replace By to replace the entire line, not only  `<ul class="lista_3">`  ?

Comment: Use `\A(.*?<ul class="lista_3">.*?\n)[^\r\n]*<ul class="lista_3">[^\r\n]*(\R.*)?\z`, replace with `$1NEW_LINE$2`

Answer (score 2):

Using 3 capture groups you could replace both lines with 1 'Find in file' replace

For example:

Find what : `(<ul class="lista_3">)(\s+)(\1)(\s+\1)`
Replace with : `<ul class="lista_1">\2<ul class="lista_2">\4`
Search mode : Regular expression

If there's text (other than newlines) between those repeated tags then the text between the tags also needs to be captured, so it can be used in the replace string.

Find what : `(<ul class="lista_3">)(.*?)(\1)(?=.*?\1)`
Replace with : `<ul class="lista_1">\2<ul class="lista_2">`
Search mode : Regular expression **(with the `. matches newlines` checked)**

Note that a positive lookahead was used this time.
Since it's not like that last one would need to be replaced.
It's just checking that there's indeed a 3th of that back-referenced capture group 1.

However, if there are more repeats of that group then it should be done without the lookahead, I suppose.

Find what : `(<ul class="lista_3">)(.*?)(\1)(.*?\1)`
Replace with : `<ul class="lista_1">\2<ul class="lista_2">\4`
Search mode : Regular expression **(with the `. matches newlines` checked)**

Comment: yes, but if I had more words on those lines, after those instances, what will be the regex?

Comment: Updated the answer. Notepad++ uses the regex engine from C++ Boost, which is semi-compatible with the regex from Perl. So a tester for the PCRE or "Perl Compatible Regular Expressions" regex engine can be used to test a Notepad++ regex, if you don't use any of the super special magic regex tricks. Therefore, [here's a test](https://regex101.com/r/pD1zA1/1)